Question about the line graph L(G)
Definition:‎‎

‎If $e$ is an edge in $G$ connecting $u$ and $v$‎, ‎then the degree of $e$ in the line graph $L(G)$ is equal to $d_{G}(u)+d_{G}(v)-2$, so $d_{L(G)} = d_G(u) + d_G(v) - 2$. Then‎
$$
\sum_{e\in V(L(G))} 
= \sum_{uv\in E(V(G))} \bigl(d_G(u) + d_G(v)‎ - ‎2\bigr) 
= \Biggl[\sum_{uv\in E(V(G))} d_G(u)^{2}\Biggr]‎ ‎- \; 2m(G),
$$
‎where $m$ is the number of edges.
‎Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite simple graph‎. ‎The Sombor index $SO(G)$ of $G$ is defined as
$$
SO(G) = \sum_{uv\in E(G)} \sqrt{d_u^2 + d_v^2}‎, 
$$
‎where $d_u$ is the degree of vertex $u$ in $G$‎.
‎

‎‎‏‎Question:‎
Every time the line graph $L(G)$ is repeated, Will the value of Sambor index increase?
‎
‎I mean, is it ‎$ ‎SO(G)< SO(L(G)) < SO(L(L(G))) < SO(L(L(L(G)))) <‎\cdots ‎<‎\cdots‎‎‎$‎‏ for all graphs with order $n> 4$ true‎‏?
‎

It seems to fail if $G$ is a cycle graph, since then $L(G)\cong G$.

@ZachTeitler It also fails for a path graph since $L(P_{n+1})\cong P_n$.

It seems to right if G is a regular graph, is it right?

For what graph is this relationship established? Help me.

For a regular graph you can calculate it exactly.  For general connected graphs with at least 5 vertices, I think the answer is that $SO(L(G)) > SO(G)$ unless $G$ is a path or a cycle (but I didn't prove it). If $G$ is not a path or a cycle and has at least 5 vertices, then $L(G)$ is also not a path or cycle, so the increase continues.
